# Error when running Glue studio job. (InvalidInputException:Invalid S3 resource)

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-lake-formation

I am new to AWS glue. I have uploaded my csv to an S3 bucket and crawled into a Data Catalog database table. Looking fine with AWS Athena.

I then tried to start a glue studio job to remap the key. However it gives me an error I couldn't find the solution. The IAM role I used for the glue job has access to the S3 bucket. No idea about Lake Formation, I tried everything in LF to enable access (with the LF-tag, S3 location registration." No idea what's going on. Could someone shed some light? Thanks!

```
npy4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o93.getDynamicFrame.\n: java.lang.RuntimeException: class com.amazonaws.services.gluejobexecutor.model.InvalidInputException:Invalid S3 resource (Service: AWSLakeFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInputException; Request ID: 208fb8b8-62d9-4ebb-9107-bd4b3b6e8119; Proxy: null) (Service: AWSGlueJobExecutor; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInputException; Request ID: 0685c719-d128-4596-87db-def2d5837a14; Proxy: null)
```

Error log:

```
2022-10-24 15:20:58,739 ERROR [main] glueexceptionanalysis.GlueExceptionAnalysisListener (Logging.scala:logError(9)): [Glue Exception Analysis] {
"Event": "GlueETLJobExceptionEvent",
"Timestamp": 1666624858735,
"Failure Reason": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/shipping_remap_1_yxd.py\", line 19, in <module>\n    transformation_ctx=\"AmazonS3_node1666619146221\",\n  File \"/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/dynamicframe.py\", line 629, in from_catalog\n    return self._glue_context.create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog(db, table_name, redshift_tmp_dir, transformation_ctx, push_down_predicate, additional_options, catalog_id, **kwargs)\n  File \"/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/context.py\", line 188, in create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog\n    return source.getFrame(**kwargs)\n  File \"/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/data_source.py\", line 36, in getFrame\n    jframe = self._jsource.getDynamicFrame()\n  File \"/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py\", line 1305, in __call__\n    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)\n  File \"/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py\", line 111, in deco\n    return f(*a, **kw)\n  File \"/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py\", line 328, in get_return_value\n    format(target_id, \".\", name), value)\npy4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o93.getDynamicFrame.\n: java.lang.RuntimeException: class com.amazonaws.services.gluejobexecutor.model.InvalidInputException:Invalid S3 resource (Service: AWSLakeFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInputException; Request ID: 208fb8b8-62d9-4ebb-9107-bd4b3b6e8119; Proxy: null) (Service: AWSGlueJobExecutor; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInputException; Request ID: 0685c719-d128-4596-87db-def2d5837a14; Proxy: null)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.remote.LakeformationCredentialsProvider.refresh(LakeformationCredentialsProvider.scala:50)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.remote.LakeformationCredentialsProvider.<init>(LakeformationCredentialsProvider.scala:77)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.remote.MichiganAWSCredentialProviderProxy$.get(MichiganAWSCredentialProviderProxy.scala:14)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FileSchemeWrapper.setHadoopConfiguration(FileSchemeWrapper.scala:43)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FileSchemeWrapper.executeWith(FileSchemeWrapper.scala:82)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FileSchemeWrapper.executeWithQualifiedScheme(FileSchemeWrapper.scala:90)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.HadoopDataSource.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:556)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.DataSource.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:101)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.DataSource.getDynamicFrame$(DataSource.scala:101)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.HadoopDataSource.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:246)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)\n\tat py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)\n\tat py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)\n\tat py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)\n\tat py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)\n\tat py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)\n",
"Stack Trace": [
    {
        "Declaring Class": "get_return_value",
        "Method Name": "format(target_id, \".\", name), value)",
        "File Name": "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
        "Line Number": 328
    },
    {
        "Declaring Class": "deco",
        "Method Name": "return f(*a, **kw)",
        "File Name": "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
        "Line Number": 111
    },
    {
        "Declaring Class": "__call__",
        "Method Name": "answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)",
        "File Name": "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
        "Line Number": 1305
    },
    {
        "Declaring Class": "getFrame",
        "Method Name": "jframe = self._jsource.getDynamicFrame()",
        "File Name": "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/data_source.py",
        "Line Number": 36
    },
    {
        "Declaring Class": "create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog",
        "Method Name": "return source.getFrame(**kwargs)",
        "File Name": "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/context.py",
        "Line Number": 188
    },
    {
        "Declaring Class": "from_catalog",
        "Method Name": "return self._glue_context.create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog(db, table_name, redshift_tmp_dir, transformation_ctx, push_down_predicate, additional_options, catalog_id, **kwargs)",
        "File Name": "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/dynamicframe.py",
        "Line Number": 629
    },
    {
        "Declaring Class": "<module>",
        "Method Name": "transformation_ctx=\"AmazonS3_node1666619146221\",",
        "File Name": "/tmp/shipping_remap_1_yxd.py",
        "Line Number": 19
    }
],
"Last Executed Line number": 19,
"script": "shipping_remap_1_yxd.py"
```

}

Comment: Could you update your question with a code example?